# Time to travel hops networking

Tags: networking, ping

If two machines are on the same network, as in, they both are connected to the same default gateway, does sending out a ping from one machine to the other make the other reply with a TTL value decremented by 1 or by 0?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

`TTL` decreases with each hop from one machine to another until the destination is reached. It basically counts the number of machines on the route from source to destination. The reply (`pong`) is a completely different message with new `TTL` that has no relation to the `ping` message.
The reason for that is that the `ping-pong` is an `application layer` interaction and `TTL` belongs to `transport layer` of the network [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).